# print JSON value in table which come through ajax response using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, for-loop, foreach

I am not able to print the value getting from this [JSON response](https://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor/cb7b2ead). I am using jQuery and Ajax.
In success response, I am using for-each function for print all the data,
In my JSON response, there are multiple trees.
When I print single data it working by using this code.

```
console.log(response.saleOrderDTO.billingAddress.name) //for fetching name
```

but I am trying to append all data available in `billingAddress` as in my attachment file, when I used this below code it says `undifined` not working.

```
<table id="table2"></table>

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  cache: false,
  timeout: 10000,
  success: function (response) {
    var response = $.parseJSON(response);
    $.each(response.saleOrderDTO.billingAddress, function(i, item) {
         $("table#table2").append(`
             <tr><td>${item.name}</td></tr>
          `)
    });
  }
})
```

Please help - [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/twt2shiv/zae5ku3g/2/)

Comment: `$.each` expect an array as the first argument, but not an object https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Just use `console.log(response.saleOrderDTO.billingAddress.name); // Output: "Sushant"` to retrieve the name.

Comment: can I use this code `https://jsfiddle.net/twt2shiv/zae5ku3g/2/` but it not working

Comment: You might try `Object.values(billingAddress).map(value => {});` to iterate over object properties. Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/vyspiansky/db2weos3/ or https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/oNBKxwV?editors=0012

Comment: but in your how I echo "id","name","state" also without double quotes

Comment: It's not clear what exactly do you need. However check `Object.entries` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries Might be helpful for you.